# Ploting same color for each column in matrix for 'n' iterations

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a matrix `A` of size `(N, 80)`, Where values of `A`are updated every `N`th iteration.

How can I use a color vector of 80 corresponding to the matrix `A`? I do not want to use a `for` loop, as it consumes lot of time in every iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by "a color vector of 80 corresponding to the matrix A"?

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: `for` loops are actually not so slow any longer, since the engine was overhauld for R2015a

Comment: Look at the very bottom of the documentation page for plot http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html in the More About section. It says - "You can change the default colors and line styles by setting default values for the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties" but its not very clear to me how. If not, get the handle to your line objects when you plot and then loop through the objects to assign a color to each. As said above `for` loops are not so slow any longer.

Comment: It doesn't even matter if they're slow. Write functioning code **first**, then worry about optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a color matrix `color` consisting of RGB triplets for the 80 different colors you have (this would be an 80 x 3 matrix). Set it as the Default Axes Color Order by using:

```
>> set(groot,'defaultAxesColorOrder',colors)
>> plot(A) % Will plot the 80 columns with colors corresponding to color
```

To reset your default Axes colors to factory

```
>> set(groot,'defaultAxesColorOrder','factory')
```